# Race condition, my doubt on Peterson's algorithm vs. C

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, threads, critical-section

I have seen this C code showing an implentation of Peterson's Critical Section algorithm. It is obviously skeletal and hardwired for two threads but the logic is supposed to be correct in detail.

[image: Peterson's algorithm in pseudocode]

Despite reading and talking I remain with a grain of doubt about the following line (and the similar line for Thread B):

> `while (turn == 1 && flag1) skip;

When it is compiled, the while clause will generate multiple instructions which it seems to me can lead to a race condition in a pre-emptive scheduling model.

While I trust the proofs etc. I have not seen a good way to refute my concern.

(I know this is an oldie but goodie so feel free to respond with a link.)

Comment: That code is not C code, It is pseudocode based on the style of C code.

Comment: I realize that but I think it does get the point across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When it is compiled, the while clause will generate multiple instructions which it seems to me can lead to a race condition in a pre-emptive scheduling model.

This is the technical beauty of Peterson's algorithm. Even though there could be many possible execution paths for this short and simple-looking code, it guarantees mutual exclusion, progress and bounded waiting. (Bounded waiting is not guaranteed for more than two participating threads, though).

On first sight, it looks there is a race condition on which thread will set the value of "turn", especially in a pre-emptive scheduling model. However, a close analysis will show neither does this race condition corrupt the mutual exclusion nor does it prevent progress. Here is the basic analysis on mutual exclusion by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm#Mutual_exclusion), adapted for the variable names here.

> `Thread A` and `Thread B` can never be in their critical sections at the same time. If `Thread A` is in its critical section, then `flag0` is `TRUE`. In addition,
>
> - either `flag1` is `FALSE`, meaning that `Thread B` has left its critical section,
> - or `turn` is `0`, meaning that `Thread B` is just now trying to enter its critical section, but graciously waiting,
> - or `Thread B` is right before the line `turn = 0`, trying to enter its critical section, after setting `flag1` to `TRUE` but before setting `turn` to `0` and busy waiting.
>
> So if both threads are in their critical sections, then we conclude that the state must satisfy `flag0` and `flag1` and `turn = 0` and `turn = 1`. No state can satisfy both `turn = 0` and `turn = 1`, so there can be no state where both threads are in their critical sections.

Note that the analysis above is programming-language independent. It does not matter you use C, Java, Python, assembly, etc.

Note that the analysis above only assumes that the code/instruction in each thread is executed/implemented serially. Whether there is a race condition to set `turn` or whether the scheduling model is pre-emptive does not matter.

As you could have insisted, it is not convincing enough with the explanation above, nor with many similar high-level arguments in textbooks. Currency is too subtle, delicate and illusive for involving propositions to be proved easily, usually.

People have spent great efforts proving propositions involving concurrency (in a pre-emptive scheduling model). For example, Uri Abraham's paper [The assertional versus Tarskian methods](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Eabraham/courses/Concurrency14/Peterson/Assertional-Tarskian2.pdf) presents two formal proofs on the correctness of the Peterson's algorithm,  together with an enlightening and convincing clarification on what is a formal proof. You will be convinced beyond any doubt if you have finished reading it or just half of it. (I do not remember whether I have finished reading that paper, though.)

Comment: Thanks for the outstanding response :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, one could model this in one's favourite model-checking language such as Promela and explore the model with [spin](https://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html).

With the basic atomic awaits, the code could look like this

```
#include "critical3.h"

bool wantp = false, wantq = false, last = 1

active proctype p()
{
  do
    :: non_critical_section('p');
wap:   wantp = true;
       last = 1;
       (!wantq || last == 0);
csp:   critical_section('p');
       wantp = false
  od
}

active proctype q()
{
  do
    :: non_critical_section('q');
waq:   wantq = true;
       last = 0;
       (!wantp || last == 1);
csq:   critical_section('q');
       wantq = false
  od
}

ltl mutex { !<>(p@csp && q@csq) }
ltl dlf   { [](p@wap && q@waq -> <>(p@csp || q@csq)) }
ltl aud   { [](p@wap && ([](!q@waq)) -> <>p@csp) }
ltl ee    { [](p@wap -> <>p@csp) }
```

where the included `critical3.h` is

```
/* 
  Definitions for 2 process critical sections; derived from Ben-Ari's.
*/

inline critical_section(proc) {
     printf("MSC: %c in CS\n", proc);
}

inline non_critical_section(proc) {
  printf("MSC: %c in non-CS\n", proc);
  do                            /* non-deterministically choose how
                                   long to stay, even forever */
    :: true ->
         skip
    :: true ->
         break
  od
}
```

Here's a version with explicit non-atomic awaits.

```
#include "critical3.h"

bool wantp = false, wantq = false, last = 1

active proctype p()
{
  do
    :: non_critical_section('p');
wap:   wantp = true;
       last = 1;
tp:    if
         :: !wantq -> goto csp
         :: else
       fi
       if
         :: last == 0 -> goto csp
         :: else -> goto tp
       fi
csp:   critical_section('p');
       wantp = false
  od
}

active proctype q()
{
  do
    :: non_critical_section('q');
waq:   wantq = true;
       last = 0;
tq:    if
         :: !wantp -> goto csq
         :: else -> skip
       fi
       if
         :: last == 1 -> goto csq
         :: else -> goto tq
       fi
csq:   critical_section('q');
       wantq = false
  od
}

ltl mutex { !<>(p@csp && q@csq) }
ltl dlf   { [](p@wap && q@waq -> <>(p@csp || q@csq)) }
ltl aud   { [](p@wap && ([](!q@waq)) -> <>p@csp) }
ltl ee    { [](p@wap -> <>p@csp) }
```

Exploring these models with spin reveals that both have the 4 claimed properties of a mutual exclusion algorithm, *mutual exclusion* (formalised as LTL property `mutex`), _deadlock-freedom (`dlf`), *absence of unnecessary delay* (`aud`), and *eventual entry* (`ee`). The last 3 require weak fairness, otherwise the execution could end with the other process doing infinitely many steps in its non-critical section.

Crucially, this model is faithful only for sequentially consistent hardware. Modern multi-core CPUs do *not* satisfy that assumption. One could use [fence instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) to salvage correctness Peterson on architectures with weaker memory models (such as ARM's PSO and Intel's TSO).

Comment: Thanks for the outstanding response :)